# Feathers and wind simulation in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I would like to create a bird simulation that will use its wings to interact with the surrounding air. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What specifically do you want the outcome of this simulation to be? What have you tried so far, and where have you run into trouble getting the outcomes you want?

Comment: @DMGregory this http://mrl.snu.ac.kr/research/ProjectBird/BirdFlight_TOG.pdf , in regards to trouble, correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as i looked - it doesn't seem like air simulation is part of unity, where Wind Zones are working in pulses. Also nothing on the asserts store

Comment: Expecting an engine to do this for you out of the box is a recipe for disappointment. 99.999% of games don't involve physically accurate simulation of feather aerodynamics after all, so it would be a very wasteful feature to include in a general-purpose game engine. But, Unity has a full-fledged physics sim in which you can apply and integrate whatever forces your game's model of bird flight deems appropriate. How have you tried applying forces to your bird so far?

Comment: Yea fair point I was expecting too much from a game Physics engine, instead of using a force field or a particle system the easiest way is to apply force vector to based on the wing delta position, which is easy to implement when the bird is facing forward with its back up, but gets tricky once you count in rotation ( for example when the bird is turning / doing a back-flip )

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the specific problem you've encountered in applying a force vector to a rotated bird? We might be able to help you solve that specific issue.